# solr error: unknown field ignored_stream_source_info

Tags: solr

I am working on solar 4.2 on windows 7.

My schema :

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"
required="true"/>
<field name="author" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="comments" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="keywords" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="contents" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="revision_number" type="string" indexed="true"
stored="true" />
(dynamic field name is ignored_* )
```

I get an error:

```
[doc=8]unknown field ignored_stream_source_info
```

What does this error message mean?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the configuration for the `fmap.content` content parameter.
`fmap.content` by default maps to the text field which is not defined in the schema.xml specified by you. You can pass the parameter `fmap.content=contents` to map it to the contents field.
You can modify the solrconfig.xml to specify the same.

Comment: i did map contents as follows: <str name="fmap.content">contents</str> in solrconfig.xml

Comment: <requestHandler name="/update/extract" class="org.apache.solr.handler.
extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="fmap.content">contents</str>
<str name="lowernames">true</str>
<str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>
<str name="captureAttr">true</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler> This is in my solrconfig.xml,but i still get the same same

Comment: Is there something like fmap.contents which i shall add in schema.xml??

Comment: nope .. you can restart solr and reindex again to check if it works.

Comment: should i add config tag for tika.config ??

Comment: what is the problem then? i referred solr cookbook 4 and this link http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler

Comment: yes i get the same error. URL is :curl "http://localhost:8080/solr/update/extract?literal.id=1&commit=true"
-F "myfile=@abc.txt"

Comment: Error got resolved,solution was <dynamic field /> must be within <fields> tag.